# VBS CurrentDirectory trouble

Tags: vbscript, path, directory

I have a very simple script, which only prints current directory. That's the code:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wscript.Echo (WshShell.CurrentDirectory)
```

This script is called from `.exe` file. It works fine until the calling executable was run directly. If I create a link to exe-file and launch it, then it runs my `.vbs` and it prints the directory of link, not the `.exe` itself! How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get help from FileSystemObject, (*vbscript example*) :

```
scriptdir=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Wscript.Echo scriptdir
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe it's somehow clumsy, but I've discovered a workable solution. The idea is simple: get full script name and a short one. Then subtract the second from the first.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wscript.Echo (Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName)))
```